# Angular 7 import primitive extensions from an angular library

Tags: angular, typescript, module, shared-libraries

So I wrote my own primitive extensions and it works well. I use them on several projects and now it's time to centralize my work in a library.

> *Angular library first attempt*

So far so good, the services and components are working well. Now I import my extensions like in the other apps:

**extensions.ts**

```js
interface String {
    someFunction(this: string): boolean;
}

String.prototype.someFunction= function (this: string): boolean {
    return !this;
};
```

and in my **my-lib.module.ts**

```js
import './path/to/my/extensions';
```

**public-api.ts**:

```js
export * from './lib/core/extensions';
```

Then I create a package of my library with **npm pack** and install it in my app with **npm install /absolute/path/to/my-lib**. Once my library is installed, i check if everything is ok.

Everything is ok except the extensions. How can I use **my-lib/extensions** in the projects that import my library?

If I try in my **app.module.ts**

```js
import 'my-lib/extensions';
```

I have an error:

```
Failed to compile.

./src/app/app.module.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'my-lib/extensions' in 'C:\Angular\MyApp\src\app'
```

Any idea? I'm kinda lost
(we assume that all the path are correct)

Answer (score 0):

If my-lib is not under your app folder, you need to include it in your tsconfig.json file...

```
"include": [
    "path/to/my-lib"
]
```

Comment: I create my package locally and then install it via the npm install. Is it still not enough?

Comment: Then, the correct thing to do would be to transpile to js and make the js files and d.ts files available in your package. If you still want to provide raw ts files in your package, then yes, you need to include the path to your library in tsconfig.json

Comment: Still cant make it work. Here are the steps I do: 1) edit my source in the my-lib project. 2) npm build my-lib 3) in the generated output dir: npm pack and then copy the .tgz file to a local repository. 4) in the client app (MyApp) I install my libreary with npm install /path/to/my-lib

I think I followed all the steps mentionned in all the tutorials I read so why is it still not working?

Your solution is good if I dont install the package with the npm command, isn't it?

Comment: Your mom package should have js files and d.ts files. Not raw rypescript